# Char has a different size than a string

Tags: c++, string, char, sizeof, function-parameter

I was working with a program that uses a function to set a new value in the registry, I used a `const char *` to get the value. However, the size of the value is only four bytes. I've tried to use `std::string` as a parameter instead, it didn't work.
I have a small example to show you what I'm talking about, and rather than solving my problem with the function I'd like to know the reason it does this.

```
#include <iostream>


void test(const char * input)
{
    std::cout << input;
    std::cout << "\n" << sizeof("THIS IS A TEST") << "\n" << sizeof(input) << "\n";
    /* The code above prints out the  size of an explicit string (THIS IS A TEST), which is 15. */
    /* It then prints out the size of input, which is 4.*/

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) //Printed out each character, added the size of each to sum and printed it out.
    //The result was 15.
    {
        sum += sizeof(input[i]);
        std::cout << input[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n" << sum;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    test("THIS IS A TEST");
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

Output:
THIS IS A TEST
15
4
THIS IS A TEST
15
```

What's the correct way to get string parameters? Do I have to loop through the whole array of characters and print each to a string (the value in the registry was only the first four bytes of the char)? Or can I use `std::string` as a parameter instead?
I wasn't sure if this was SO material, but I decided to post here as I consider this to be one of my best sources for programming related information.

Comment: Protip: Instead of using `std::cout << ... << "\n";`, consider using `std::cout << ... << std::endl;` The latter flushes the output buffer and is the more popular convention in C++.

Comment: @teedayf, thanks for the tip! I had no idea, I've always used "\n" because it looked better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(input)` is the size of a `const char*` What you want is `strlen(input) + 1`

`sizeof("THIS IS A TEST")` is size of a `const char[]`. `sizeof` gives the size of the array when passed an array type which is why it is 15 .

For `std::string` use `length()`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried strlen (which only seems to be available in `string.h`), the output was 14 and not 15. Why is that?

Comment: @Griffin `strlen` returns the number of characters not including `'\0'`. It does not return the size of the array. `"THIS IS A TEST"` has the `'\0'` included.

Comment: sizeof("...") gives you the size of the constant array, which includes the terminating zero byte. strlen() doesn't count the null byte.

Comment: @bames53 Yeah, I just realized that and updated post. Haven't used strlen in ages.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` gives a size based on the *type* you give it as a parameter. If you use the name of a variable, `sizeof` still only bases its result on the type of that variable. In the case of `char *whatever`, it's telling you the size of a pointer to char, *not* the size of the zero-terminated buffer it's point at. If you want the latter, you can use `strlen` instead. Note that `strlen` tells you the length of the *content* of the string, *not* including the terminating `'\0'`. As such, if (for example) you want to allocate space to duplicate a string, you need to add 1 to the result to tell you the total space occupied by the string.

Yes, as a rule in C++ you normally want to use `std::string` instead of pointers to char. In this case, you can use `your_string.size()` (or, equivalently, `your_string.length()`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice explanation, although I don't know how to apply `std::string` as a parameter. When doing `function("test");` and you have defined it as `void function(std::string input)` it complains about not being able to convert `std::string` to `const char*`. `strlen()` works though, so I might aswell use that.

Comment: You can get a (constant) c-style string from a C++ string using `your_string.c_str()`. What you receive becomes invalid when/if you modify the underlying C++ string though.

Comment: To add to @JerryCoffin's comment, you'd also want to pass a reference to the string than the string itself in a scenario like this, unless you want to actually copy the string, because C++ is pass-by-value. So your function signature would be more efficient as `void function(std::string& input)` or `void function(const std::string& input)`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is a C++ object, which cannot be passed to most APIs.  Most API's take `char*` as you noticed, which is *very* different from a `std::string`.  However, since this is a common need, `std::string` has a function for that: `c_str`.

```
std::string input;
const char* ptr = input.c_str();  //note, is const
```

In C++11, it is now also safe-ish to do this:

```
char* ptr = &input[0]; //nonconst
```

and you can alter the characters, but the size is fixed, and the pointer is invalidated if you call any mutating member of the `std::string`.

As for the code you posted, `"THIS IS A TEST"` has the type of `const char[15]`, which has a size of 15 bytes.  The `char* input` however, has a type `char*` (obviously), which has a size of 4 on your system.  (Might be other sizes on other systems)

To find the size of a c-string pointed at by a `char*` pointer, you can call `strlen(...)` if it is NULL-terminated.  It will return the number of characters before the first NULL character.

Answer (score 0):

If the registry you speak of is the Windows registry, it may be an issue of Unicode vs. ASCII.
Modern Windows stores almost all strings as Unicode, which uses 2 bytes per character. 
If you try to put a Unicode string into an std::string, it may be getting a 0 (null), which some implementations of string classes treat as "end of string."

You may try using a std::wstring (wide string) or vector< wchar_t > (wide character type). These can store strings of two-byte characters.

sizeof() is also not giving you the value you may think it is giving you. Your system probably runs 32-bit Windows -- that "4" value is the size of the pointer to the first character of that string.
If this doesn't help, please post the specific results that occur when you use std::string or std::wstring (more than saying that it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, the size of a const char * != the size of a const char[] (if they are equal, it's by coincidence).  The former is a pointer.  A pointer, in the case of your system, is 4 bytes REGARDLESS of the datatype.  It could be int, char, float, whatever.  This is because a pointer is always a memory address, and is numeric.  Print out the value of your pointer and you'll see it's actually 4 bytes.  const char[] now, is the array itself and will return the length of the array when requested.